# Where in the US is this statue located?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, locate-this

[image: I only know this place is in the US]I only know this place is in the US. Please help me. I tried googling but found nothing.

Comment: [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=EN) is a wonderful thing.

Comment: Also it's not a statue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the [Washington monument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Monument) on the Mall in Washington, DC, seen from the Lincoln Memorial.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of feeding a troll: It's the Washington Monument.  https://s.abcnews.com/images/Politics/gty_washington_monument_kb_1405012_16x9_992.jpg